# Pandas: set values in a Series based on another Series with some index in common and some not

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have two series with some index in common and some not, for example:

```
a = pd.Series({1:None, 2:None, 3:None})
b = pd.Series({1:1, 2:2, 4:4})
```

I want to set the values in `a` with the values in `b` with corresponding index:

**Expected outcome:**

```
In: print(a)
Out: 
    1       1
    2       2
    3    None
```

I tried:

```
a.loc[b.index] = b.values
```

But obviously it raises a KeyError with the index 4.

Which is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `a.update(b)` ?

Comment: Thanks I did not know about the update() command! If you post your answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `a.update(b)` to fill in the values.